# Serve images outside web application

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jetty, tapestry

I want to access static files, which are outside my web application in a known directory. I have read many options over the www, but I have still some questions about this.

Basically I want to declare a context for the defaultservlet of my application server. In my case I'm trying with the Tapestry Tutorial, which is a Maven based project and imported to eclipse.

The idea was to create a httpservlet, which gets the file from the location. Do someone of you know where I can grab an example of such a servlet and how I can call him? I know that the servlet must be probably declared as a service, because all pages of the application need to access the files, but I could also be mistaken and it is enough to import it, let say, in the layout page (All pages use the layout.tml file). I basically don't have any clue how to do it with a servlet. Can someone show me the light?

Tank you very much.

Comment: please edit your question so, that there will be only one specific question in one post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tapestry way of doing this is by contributing an [AssetRequestHandler](http://tapestry.apache.org/current/apidocs/org/apache/tapestry5/services/assets/AssetRequestHandler.html) and an [AssetFactory](http://tapestry.apache.org/current/apidocs/org/apache/tapestry5/services/AssetFactory.html).

AppModule.java

```
public static void contributeAssetDispatcher(
        MappedConfiguration<String, AssetRequestHandler> config,
        ResourceStreamer streamer)
{
   config.add("staticfile", new StaticFileAssetRequestHandler(streamer));
}

public void contributeAssetSource(
        MappedConfiguration<String, AssetFactory> config)
{
    config.add("staticfile", new StaticFileAssetFactory());
}
```

Then in your tml you can use

```
<img src="${asset:staticfile:path/to/myFile.jpg}" />
```

Take a look at the ContextAssetRequestHandler, ClasspathAssetRequestHandler, ContextAssetFactory and ClasspathAssetFactory for inspiration.

Be careful not to open up a security hole where a hacker can access any file on your server by passing file paths prefixed with `../../`

Answer (score 3):

Another simpler solution is to create a page which returns a stream response

```
public class StaticFile {
    StreamResponse onActivate(String fileName) {
        return new StaticFileStreamResponse(fileName);
    }
}
```

Then in another component / page

```
@Inject ComponentResources resources;

public Link getStaticFileLink() {
   return resources.createPageRenderLinkWithContext("StaticFile", "path/to/myFile.jpg");
}
```

TML

```
<img src="${StaticFileLink}" />
```

But then you won't take advantage of tapestry's 304 NOT_MODIFIED response as in my other solution.

Comment: Quick question about this response - I suppose that means that in the call to createPageRenderLInkWithContext, if the path to the file can be changed then the file does not need to be static? I am looking at a way to serve local files to users but they are not known until running.

Comment: Are you asking if "path/to/myFile.jpg" could be a runtime value? Of course it can, it's just a String :)

Comment: Yep, I actually implemented this (with a few changes though) and it is working great, thanks uklance - I'll upvote.